# Gradle build variants and flavors, how could i put this into practice?

Tags: android, gradle, build-settings, android-productflavors

I have searched and researched and I have performed a lot of tests but I am still stuck.

Because an image is better than an explication, i'm stuck on this one....

[image]

"Demo" and "main" have a different sourcetree (main -> release, demo -> demo).

I want to make inerhit other flavors like in the picture.

Somebody can help me ? What's the pattern to apply ?